# xcode 11.6.x and mac os 10.15.x build slow / no multi-thread

Tags: xcode, building

Starting sometime late last week, our fairly large builds are no longer multi-threading.  We have gone back in time in the repo, etc, and it continues.

We are checking out our side, but has anyone else seen this?

Scripting and Interactive builds.

It starts out using all of the CPUs / threads and then backs off to one at a time in the compile stream.

We have done all of the normal stuff and we are not new at this.

Comment: We backed off of the new build system to the old one.  This fixed the badness somewhat but not as good as the new system when it was working.

Comment: XCode 12 Beta 6 same issue